# How to transliterate 中文 in Mandarin pronunciation to Korean?

Tags: pronunciation

I am working on an art project that I would like to collect the hundreds of different transliterations of 「中文」 zhōng wén in Mandarin Chinese. (Pronunciation available, for example, through [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=zh-CN&tl=ko&text=%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87&op=translate).)

How can I transliterate zhōng wén in Korean? (For example, "zhong wen" would be the closest pronunciation in English.)

Comment: Just for clarification do you want a Korean alphabet which helps Korean to learn Mandarin? I.e. 管理 => 관 리, 今天 => 찐톈

Comment: In English, it's more like "Joong Wen".

Answer (score 4):

There is [a standard](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000109&mn_id=97) for that, established by the National Institute of the Korean Language.

According to that, zhōngwén should be transliterated to "종원".

ㅈ/ㅅ is used for pinyin "zh/sh", and ㅉ/ㅆ is used for pinyin "z/s".

Comment: Things are usually easier with established standards, but with an established pinyin system, I reckon there will be trouble finding transliterations for languages written in the Latin alphabet.

Comment: @KevinLi What do you mean?

Comment: Example: to an Italian, the sound would be spelled “giogn uen”.

Answer (score 2):

You mean listen to the sound that you linked and write it down in Korean, right?

If so, I think "쭝원" would be the closest pronunciation in Korean.

Answer (score 0):

Standards-wise of course @MujjinGun is correct. But the standard transliteration of my own name in English is *Cheong* and no one's ever said it right. (It sounds more like *Jung*.) The word *Korea* itself comes from 고려 which sounds like "goh-ryuh" but got transliterated as "kor-yo," which resulted in me believing old Korea was called 골요 until... 2 minutes ago.

So, if the goal is fidelity to pronunciation by modern tongue, then as a Korean who went to a community-run **中文**学校 for some years I agree with @Nocturnez's answer,

> 쭝원

But I wanted to add my own answer to explain a couple things.

Strangely, the real vowel sound is somewhere between @MujjinGun's ㅗ (as in "d**oo**r") and @Nocturnez's ㅜ (as in "t**oo**l"). I say "strangely" because I never would have logically thought there was a sound "between" those two, which even the Korean graphemes ㅗ and ㅜ suggest are opposites. Your mouth shapes like you're going to say "oo" but it sounds more like "oo". (Got that?)

Now pictorially there *is* the ㅡ (as in "dung**eo**n") that appears to be neither ㅗ or ㅜ and arguably is "between." Which is totally irrelevant reasoning, but interestingly in order to prounounce 中, there *is* a hint of that ㅡ sound *in addition* to the strange mix of ㅗ and ㅜ! Just goes to show how mindbogglingly complex phonetics can be.

As for the consonant, ㅉ is absolutely closer to correct than ㅈ.

#### tl;dr

The real sound is somewhere between the following 3...

> 쭝, 쫑, 쯩

and the following 2 even though I didn't dive into this one...

> 원, 은

Some say I was destined to write this answer, since the word in question is a homonym of my own name 정원일 (鄭元一) in each language...